# What is a good way to conditionally enable a strategy for authentication?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a `DebugStrategy` that will help with development, but I don't want to enable it in production.

We are using the `GqlAuthGuard` for graphql as explained in the documentation. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

let strategies = ['firebase'];
if (process.env.DEBUG) {
  strategies.push('debug');
}

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(strategies) {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

It works, but it feels pretty janky. There has to be a better way, perhaps having a list of enabled strategies in a configuration file or something, but if I do that, how can I pass those configuration parameters to the `extends AuthGuard(strategies)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could have a global `Config` object and then do:

```
extends AuthGuard(Config.auth.strategies)
```

This question is kind of subjective--personally I think what you're doing is fine since all the Auth strategies stuff is being handled in one file. It could be slightly prettier but it's not a huge deal:

```
// Using Config.prod so it can be set in other ways
// in case the ENV name changes, we also want it to
// allow 'debug' with env var TEST=true, etc...

const strategies = Config.prod ? ['firebase'] : ['firebase', 'debug'];
```